# Second thread doesn't update gui until first finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My program takes awhile to launch, so I want to create a "loading" screen for it (just a frame that appears instantly so users know it's doing something). That means a frame or JOptoinPane can be run in a separate thread immediately (see attempt below). The delay is simulated in the code below by the `Thread.sleep(3000)`.

The problem is that the JOptoinPane appears, but stays blank until the 3 second delay is over, at which point it shows up as normal. Same behavior if it is changed to another frame. The frame loads but is empty until the time is up

A loading screen that doesn't load until the rest of the program does isn't very helpful :D. How can I fix this?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LoadingTry implements Runnable{

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoadingTry window = new LoadingTry();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
        public void run () {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intializing...");

        }
    };

    public LoadingTry() {
        thread1.start();

        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {}

}
```

Comment: inventing the wheel is always harder the second time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: that first wheel seems plenty hard to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Remove parts of this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoadingTry window = new LoadingTry();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

change it to:

```
                try {
                    LoadingTry window = new LoadingTry();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        });
```

You can also replace the JOptionPane with a jframe and have an effective static splash screen